# Convert Classic Page to Modern - sharepoint server 2019 on-premises

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have a sharepoint server 2019 on-premises , I need to convert Convert Classic Pages to Modern, below code appears to work only for sharepoint online ,  How can I convert sharepoint server 2019 on-premises  Classic Page to Modern? Please advise.

ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage -Identity page1.aspx -AddPageAcceptBanner

We recently installed SharePoint Server 2019 on-premises in our DEV environment. Only Viewlists page is displaying in Modern mode, all the other pages displaying in classic mode by default.

_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=13

We need to set a streamlined view for our sites, all the pages need to be converted to modern mode. Please advise.

Comment: did you find a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, we can't convert classic page to modern page in SharePoint 2019.

The commands you mentioned are only available for SharePoint online, and we currently have no other way to convert page to modern page.

There seems to be no other way to solve your problem, I suggest you create a modern page in a modern site.